# Airflow Worker Daemon exits for no visible reason

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, airflow, worker

I have Airflow 1.9 running inside a virtual environment, set up with Celery and Redis and it works well. However, I wanted to daemon-ize the set up and used the instructions [here](https://medium.com/@vando/airflow-inside-a-virtual-enviroment-and-integrated-with-systemd-3b6427bd6430). It works well for the Webserver, Scheduler and Flower, but fails for the Worker, which is of course, the core of it all. My `airflow-worker.service` file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow celery worker daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/airflow
User=root
Group=root
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'source /home/codingincircles/airflow-master/bin/activate ; airflow worker'
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Curiously, if I run the `ExecStart` command on the CLI as is, it runs perfectly and tasks run and everything is glorious. However, when I do a `sudo service airflow-worker start`, it takes a while to return to prompt and nothing shows up in the Flower UI. When I do `journalctl -u airflow-worker.service -e`, this is what I see:

```
systemd[1]: Started Airflow celery worker daemon.
bash[12392]: [2018-04-09 21:52:41,202] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.5/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
bash[12392]: [2018-04-09 21:52:41,252] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.5/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
bash[12392]: [2018-04-09 21:52:41,578] {configuration.py:206} WARNING - section/key [celery/celery_ssl_active] not found in config
bash[12392]: [2018-04-09 21:52:41,578] {default_celery.py:41} WARNING - Celery Executor will run without SSL
bash[12392]: [2018-04-09 21:52:41,579] {__init__.py:45} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
systemd[1]: airflow-worker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: airflow-worker.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: airflow-worker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What am I doing wrong? Any other method of using Airflow works, except when I try to daemon-ize it. Even using the `-D` flag after the `airflow` commands works (like `airflow worker -D`), except I'm not sure if that is the right/safe/recommended way of using it in production and would rather make it a service and use it. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `airflow-worker.service` is trying to run the airflow worker as the `root` user. In order to run airflow worker as root, you must set `C_FORCE_ROOT="true"` in your airflow environment file (`/etc/default/airflow`). However, this is not recommended and I suspect it is not the best fix for you.

When trying to run airflow worker manually as root you should see a warning about this. Because you have not seen this warning I suspect that you are able to start the worker without issue manually because you are running it as a properly configured `airflow` user and not as `root`. Thus, the recommended solution would be to change the following lines in your `airflow-worker.service` file:

```
User=airflow
Group=airflow
```

Comment: I see. Oddly enough, I tried this again and merely restarting all the airflow services worked and it is working fine now. This, despite `sudo service airflow-worker status` showing as a white dot, which, while deeply mystifying, at least seems to work for some reason now. Any idea why?
However, in terms of best practice, are you recommending I create an airflow user and group and use the services that way?

Comment: Yes, it is my understanding that running airflow from a dedicated user and group is best practice, but through a quick search I was not able to find the documentation supporting this. I think it is safe to say in general, however, that you should avoid running applications as root whenever possible.

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Okay, yes, adding `C_FORCE_ROOT="true"` did solve the issue and everything works perfectly! So thank you for that. But I will make changes to add the `airflow` user and group and run it using that. Thank you!

Comment: Great answer. Always run your workers as dedicated 'airflow' (or other) user, not root.

Comment: New, most likely related problem. I changed my config files and everything from `root` to say `airflow`. However, the virtualenv resides within the original user's space (`/home/codingincirles`) and now, even though I added `airflow` to the sudoers list, and it is able to start the services, I get permission denied errors on the webserver and scheduler start up. Should I be installing the virtualenv and everything in this new `airflow` user's space to get everything running smoothly?

Comment: Yes. Also: by adding `airflow` to the sudoers list `airflow` now has the ability to use `sudo`, but it isn't going to use `sudo` on everything - which is why you still got permissions errors. There is nothing special about the `airflow` user name so you could use `codingincircles` as your airflow user - just so long as it is not root.